# How do I make Vue wait for Firestore to finish downloading collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm trying to connect Firestore and tui-calendar. But I can't seem to get it to function and I think, that the error is, that tui-calendar fetches the data before Firestore downloaded it. This is the code I got so far:

**This part is supposed to generate the Array that, I want to add to my calendar:**

```
var db = firebase.firestore();

var scheduleList = new Array;
var calendar = db.collection('calendar');
var wholeCalendarCollection = calendar.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {

          var dateData = new Array;
          dateData = doc.data();
          var startDate = new Date(dateData.start.seconds * 1000);
          var endDate = new Date(dateData.end.seconds * 1000);

          //all the variables used to create a date in the calendar
          var startDateString = startDate.toISOString();
          var endDateString = endDate.toISOString();
          var id = doc.id+1;
          var calendarId = id-1;
          var category = dateData.category;
          var title = dateData.title;

          var newDate = {
            id: id,
            calendarId: calendarId,
            title: title,
            category: category,
            dueDateClass: '',
            start: startDateString,
            end: endDateString
          };


          console.log(newDate);
          scheduleList.push(newDate);

        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
```

**And this part is supposed to put it in the calendar:**

```
const today = new Date();
const getDate = (type, start, value, operator) => {
start = new Date(start);
type = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1);
if (operator === '+') {
  start[`set${type}`](start[`get${type}`]() + value);
} else {
  start[`set${type}`](start[`get${type}`]() - value);
}
return start;
};
export default {
name: 'App',
components: {
  'calendar': Calendar
},
data() {
  return {
//This is my try:
    scheduleList: [
      scheduleList
    ],
//The following snippet is an example:

    /* scheduleList: [
      {
        id: '1',
        calendarId: '0',
        title: 'TOAST UI Calendar Study',
        category: 'time',
        dueDateClass: '',
        start: today.toISOString(),
        end: getDate('hours', today, 3, '+').toISOString()
      }
    ], */
```

**Also, here is my Firebase init part and my imports, if that is important:**

```
import 'tui-time-picker/dist/tui-time-picker.css';
import 'tui-date-picker/dist/tui-date-picker.css';
import 'tui-calendar/dist/tui-calendar.css';
import '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/auth'
import '@firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase-functions'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import 'firebase'
import './app.css';
import {Calendar} from '../src/index';

//firebase

var firebase = require("firebase")
Vue.use(Vuex)


// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "<My credentials>",
authDomain: "<My credentials>",
databaseURL: "<My credentials>",
projectId: "<My credentials>",
storageBucket: "<My credentials>",
messagingSenderId: "<My credentials>",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

I tested the code that's generating an array in normal JS and it worked, but I just started using Vue.js and I still don't really know much. Is there any way to output to console? Because then I could at least test if the first part of my code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps:

1. Wrap firestore code to a method and call it when component created
2. Use a flag `isLoaded` to check if data is loaded or not. You can use this flag to display loading state or hide component when data is not available.

Remember to change `isLoaded` flag to true when data is loaded

```
  this.scheduleList = scheduleList
  this.isLoaded = true
```

Component source code:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="isLoaded">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "",
  data: () => ({
    scheduleList: [],
    isLoaded: false
  }),
  created() {
    this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData() {
      var db = firebase.firestore();
      var scheduleList = new Array;
      var calendar = db.collection('calendar');
      var wholeCalendarCollection = calendar.get()
            .then(snapshot => {
              snapshot.forEach(doc => {

                var dateData = new Array;
                dateData = doc.data();
                var startDate = new Date(dateData.start.seconds * 1000);
                var endDate = new Date(dateData.end.seconds * 1000);

                //all the variables used to create a date in the calendar
                var startDateString = startDate.toISOString();
                var endDateString = endDate.toISOString();
                var id = doc.id+1;
                var calendarId = id-1;
                var category = dateData.category;
                var title = dateData.title;

                var newDate = {
                  id: id,
                  calendarId: calendarId,
                  title: title,
                  category: category,
                  dueDateClass: '',
                  start: startDateString,
                  end: endDateString
                };


                console.log(newDate);
                scheduleList.push(newDate);

              })
              this.scheduleList = scheduleList
              this.isLoaded = true
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that kind of worked. It broke my view selection (month, day, year). Where would I put this return statement? https://github.com/nhnent/toast-ui.vue-calendar/blob/master/example/App.vue#L70-L178